# DownloadFileAsync the file size is returned as -1

Tags: vb.net

so I was working in a program that downloads a file it was working good until 2 days ago (I have a local git I also returned the code back up to 1 week and still not working)
Code is from tutorials over the internet

```
Private WithEvents Downloader As New WebClient
Private Sub Downloader_DownloadProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles Downloader.DownloadProgressChanged
    Dim bytesIn As Double = Double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString())
    Dim totalBytes As Double = Double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString())
    Dim percentage As Double = bytesIn / totalBytes * 100
    totalBytes = totalBytes / 1024
    Label1.Text = String.Format("{0:0}%", percentage)
    Dim kbps As Double = e.BytesReceived / 1024
    If kbps < 1024 Then
        lblMessage.Text = String.Format("Downloading: {0:0.00} KB", kbps) & " " & String.Format("/ {0:0.00} MB", totalBytes / 1024)
    Else
        lblMessage.Text = String.Format("Downloading: {0:0.00} MB", kbps / 1024) & " " & String.Format("/ {0:0.00} MB", totalBytes / 1024)
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub Downloaded()
'stuff after it finish
End Sub
' the button calls this
Private Sub DownloadFiles()
    Try 'to download the patch
        AddHandler Downloader.DownloadFileCompleted, AddressOf Downloaded
        AddHandler Downloader.DownloadProgressChanged, AddressOf Downloader_DownloadProgressChanged
        Downloader.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("http://mytop100.eu/system.zip"), My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory & "\system.zip")
    Catch ex As Exception
        lblMessage.Text = ex.Message
    End Try
End Sub
```

after I tried to debug the situation my conclusion was that

```
e.TotalBytesToReceive
```

always returns -1 but when the download finish it shows the correct number of file size so I went here https://www.thinkbroadband.com/download and I added as link this http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/10MB.zip and it worked fine so my webhost has something wrong? my file? or I missing something in the code?
here is photos of problem in visual while download starts http://prntscr.com/gt0gx5
when finish http://prntscr.com/gt0h7v

thank you for your time

Comment: This is OT but there's no point concatenation two calls to `String.Format`. This `String.Format("Downloading: {0:0.00} KB", kbps) & " " & String.Format("/ {0:0.00} MB", totalBytes / 1024)` should be this `String.Format`. This `String.Format("Downloading: {0:0.00} KB, kbps/ {1:0.00} MB", kbps, totalBytes / 1024)`.

Comment: thank you for this but here is what happens http://prntscr.com/gt0fz9 and when finish http://prntscr.com/gt0g30

Comment: I tried downloading it using Internet Download Manager, it shows that file size is unknown, so I think it's not a problem with your vb.net app but with the website. [IDM Screen](https://prnt.sc/gt0j8q)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding

Comment: @HansPassant I am googling almost 1 hour and I cant find a way to use this on my code maybe an example I would appriciate, but thank you for the heads up

Comment: That link was supposed to help you figure out that not getting a value for TotalBytesToReceive is entirely normal.  So just don't display it when you get -1.